# Get all users, with all their images

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 mysql tables :

- users table
- table that contains gallery images for each user

**My users table looks like :**

```
id | name
---------
1   Ryan
2   James
3   Dave
```

**My user_gallery_images tables looks like :**

```
id | user_id | image
--------------------
1    1         image.jpg
2    1         image2.jpg
3    2         image3.jpg
4    2         image4.jpg
```

I was wondering if there was a query that would retrieve all users, and get all the images for that user.

The expected result should look like :

```
id | name | images
-------------------
1    Ryan   image.jpg,image2.jpg
2    James  image3.jpg,image4.jpg
3    Dave
```

Thank you

Comment: checkout `group_concat` function in mysql, all you need to use that function along with join and group by, give it a try and let us know if still having issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a LEFT JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN because you want to retrieve David who doesn't have images. And you will need to use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(image) from users u 
LEFT JOIN user_gallery_images g 
ON u.id = g.user_id GROUP by u.id
```

Note this query will work on mysql 5.7 only if you have a PRIMARY KEY on users.id. Will work on mysql < 5.7 regardless of the primary key

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
SELECT u.id,u.name GROUP_CONCAT( g.image ) AS image 
FROM users u INNER JOIN user_gallery_images g ON u.user_id=g.id 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: No, it will not return Dave

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, ugi.images
FROM users u 
JOIN user_gallery_images ugi on ugi.user_id = u.id
```